# how to send screenshots from robotframework to reportportal

Tags: robotframework, reportportal

I have a robot testcase to upgrade my box...
If there is any error, the robot framework takes the screen shot and saves the screenshot.png in reports dirctory..

Now how do i send it to reportportal.in

I am passing the reportportal info while running the robot like below..

```
robot --outputDir /opt/robotframework/reports --listener robotframework_reportportal.listener -v RP_UUID:07-aeb0-315c81358edd -v RP_ENDPOINT:http://<reportportalipaddress>:8080  -v RP_LAUNCH:TEST_UPGRADE  -v RP_PROJECT:TEST_UPGRADE /opt/robotframework/tests
```

My robot testcase

```
***Test Cases***
FROM_GUI
    Close All Browsers
    Open Browser    ${URL}    gc
    Input Text    name:username    admin
    Input Password    name:password    &{${CPE}}[cpe_password]
    Click Button    name:Continue
    Log to Console    Inside GUI ${uploadPath}//${uploadFile}
    input text    name=uploadFile    ${uploadPath}//${uploadFile}
    Page Should Contain    firmware update is in progress
    sleep    10 seconds
    click link    link=Logout
    Close All Browsers
    Sleep     180 seconds
    with open("../", "rb") as image_file:
        file_data = image_file.read()

    rp_logger.info("Some Text Here",
                            attachment={"name": "selenium-screenshot-1.png",
                                                 "data": file_data,
                                                 "mime": "image/png"})
    [Teardown]
```

In Report portal

I just see the below, can't see the screenshot

```
</td></tr><tr><td colspan="3"><a href="selenium-screenshot-1.png"><img src="selenium-screenshot-1.png" width="800px"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried 2 ways to do this (there can be more):

1. To embed the image into the report and it would also be embedded to the reportportal report.

Using the Run-on-failure functionality provided by SeleniumLibrary:
SeleniumLibrary has a handy feature that it can automatically execute a keyword if any of its own keywords fails. By default, it uses the **Capture Page Screenshot**
keyword. More info is available on the [official documentation](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html)

By default the Capture Page Screenshot has the value for file name as

> filename = selenium-screenshot-{index}.png

You can provide a custom keyword to the run_on_failure argument while loading the Selenium library.

In the custom keyword call the Capture Page Screenshot with filename=EMBED as shown below.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary    run_on_failure=Capture Screenshot and embed it into the report

*** Keywords ***
Capture Screenshot and embed it into the report
    Capture Page Screenshot    filename=EMBED
```

Note: When you embed the image into the report, the image file will not be present as a separate file in your Result folder.

2. Capturing the screenshot and sending it as an attachment:
   Create a custom python library with the below function [robotframework-reportportal documentation](https://github.com/reportportal/agent-Python-RobotFramework) , eg: utilityLib.py:

```
from robotframework_reportportal import logger

@keyword
def send_attachment_to_report_portal(path):
  with open(path, "rb") as image_file:
    file_data = image_file.read()
  logger.info("Some Text Here",
    attachment={"name": "test_name_screenshot.png",
                "data": file_data,
                "mime": "image/png"})
```

Similar to the steps in the 1st solution: Call the custom keyword via the Run-on-failure functionality

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary    run_on_failure=Capture Screenshot and attach it to reportportal
Library           utilityLib.py

*** Keywords ***
Capture Screenshot and attach it to reportportal
    ${path} =    Capture Page Screenshot
    Send attachment to report portal    ${path}
```